# Xcode UI test XCTDaemonErrorDomain Code=13 while tapping on a cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have the following Xcode UI test code that used to pass just a week ago but now I get an error

```
let cellsQuery = app.cells.matching(identifier: "identifier")
XCTAssertGreaterThan(cellsQuery.count, 0)
let cell = cellsQuery.element(boundBy: 0)
expectElementToExist(cell)
cell.tap()

final func expectElementToExist(_ element: XCUIElement, exist: Bool = true, timeout: TimeInterval = 10) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == \(exist)")
    expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)
    waitForExpectations(timeout: timeout, handler: nil)
    XCTAssertEqual(element.exists, exist)
}
```

The error I get in `cell.tap()` is the below

```
Failure fetching attributes for element <XCAccessibilityElement: 0x604001a75240> pid: 5387, elementOrHash.elementID: 105553123110000.1888: Error Domain=XCTDaemonErrorDomain Code=13 "Error copying attributes -25202" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error copying attributes -25202}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: i have added an answer for that. please use the code and let me know your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Recently i also faced the similar type of issue after upgrading my project(Swift 3.2) into XCode 9.

The issue is

```
 cell.isHittable is returning false.
```

Thats why default **tap()** method is not working for hierarchical elements.

I just did the below procedure and that worked fine.

**Step 1**: Create an extension like below

```
extension XCUIElement {
func tryClick() {
    if self.isHittable {
        self.tap()
    }
    else {
        let coordinate: XCUICoordinate = self.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx:0.5, dy:0.5))
        coordinate.doubleTap()
        //coordinate.press(forDuration: 0.5)
    }
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** click on the element using the instance method created above instead of using direct tap() method.

```
cell.tryClick()
```

**Note:** try using

```
CGVector(dx:0.5, dy:0.5) or CGVector(dx:0.0, dy:0.0)
```

Hope it will solve your issue. It worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work and `cell.isHittable` is returning `true`. Omitting the `if self.isHittable` check and forcing to use the coordinate produces the same error.

Comment: U tried with both 0.5 or 0.0 co ordinate?? Please check with that also

Comment: Then please check the element u are trying to tap is tge exact element?

Comment: Then please check the element u are trying to tap is tge exact element?

Comment: Yes it's the exact element. I have just found that it has to do with the load more logic I have in the `willDisplay cell` method. Though it isn't get called in the test scenario if I comment it out all tests pass....